# Google Sheets custom function not working (loading never stops)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple function to count colors in google sheets. It is working well when called within the script editor but its not working in sheets....
I imported function to sheets and it still loading and loading...

Is there something I am doing wrong? it is my first attempt to custom function.
the way I am calling it from cells:

```
=countbackground("#ff0000", "F11:F27")
```

my function:

```
function countBackground(color, inputRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(inputRange);
  var rowColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var count = 0;
  var newArr = [];

 // flatten array
 for(var i = 0; i < rowColors.length; i++)
 {
    newArr = newArr.concat(rowColors[i]);
 }

//count color
  for(var r = 0; r < newArr.length; r++) {
    if(newArr[r] === color){
      count++;
    }
  }
 Logger.log(rowColors);
 Logger.log(newArr);
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function worked fine for me.
Note that the code can also be shortened to

```js
function countBackground (color, inputRange) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getRange(inputRange)
  .getBackgrounds()
  .flat()
  .filter(bg => bg == color)
  .length; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! code works well but again only in script editor and not in the sheet... that shortened version of code shows me how much I must still learn. It return me unknow function error